# Can we unlock content within an iOS app based on real life accessories?

Tags: ios

We are part of the Apple MFI program.

We are designing a children’s toy that connects to our iOS app via the iPod Accessory Protocol.

There are multiple configurations of the toy.

We would like to unlock content within the app based on the configuration of the toy.

We are wondering if this is admissible under the app review guidelines? Specifically sections 11.1 and 11.2.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Thanks,
Dustin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer is in guideline 11.16 of the document:

> **11.16** Apps may enable additional approved features or functionality when used in combination with specific approved physical products (such as a toy) as long as the additional features and functionality are either completely dependent on such hardware (for example an App that is used to control a telescope) or also available through the App without the physical products, such as by way of reward for achievement or by use of IAP.